# how do I add the last part (**A light can only make 10 transitions**) to this NUSMV code?

Tags: nusmv

[QUESTION PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr3HK.png)

How do I add the last part (**A light can only make 10 transitions**)to this code?

```
MODULE light (other)
VAR

state:{r, y, g};
ASSIGN
init(state) := r;
next (state) := case
        state = r & other =r: {r, y};
        state = y : g;
        state=g : {g, r};
        TRUE : state;
    esac;

MODULE main
VAR
tl1 : process light(tl2.state);
tl2 : process light (tl1.state);
```

Comment: Seems to me you'd need to add a counter to track the number of transitions.

Comment: @KenWhite is spot on. I'd also invite you to reconsider the reason why `other = r` is included in the transition relation. It doesn't appear to be necessary given the picture you have shared.